# Right to left issue in .Net Maui when assigning the current culture to arabic

Tags: maui, maui-windows, maui-community-toolkit

I'm facing a strange issue when I assign the Arabic language as a culture by writing this line, the close, minimize and maximize buttons appear on the right corner but you can't click on them because they are actually on the left side.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar");
```

I believe this is right-to-left issue.

[image]

Comment: Add as a new issue at https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues. (Unless you find a similar issue already there.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a verified bug of Maui on Windows, you can follow up this issue: [On Windows (WinUI) Minimize, Normal, Maximize buttons behave strangely](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7751).